# Minecraft Logging into server using protocol

Tags: sockets, tcpclient, packet, minecraft, handshake

How can I realise VB.Net to send a Packet with enough information to log on into a Minecraft Server? I have these lines of codes, but I don't have a minimal idea how to get the received information that i have requested from the server :/

```
Dim MySocket As New TcpClient(IP, Port)    
Dim Socket As New Wrapped.Wrapped(MySocket.GetStream)
Socket.writeInt("4")
Socket.writeString("localhost")
Socket.writeShort("25565")
Socket.writeInt("2")
```

My final idea is to login into a server and keeping on it. I have read some things on this site, but i'm still confused: http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Handshake

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this library, it may help.  It's probably also outdated though, I doubt it's been updated for newer server versions.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/914851-csharp-c-minecraft-client-class/

Here is a link to some more network libraries to connect .NET to Minecraft.
http://wiki.vg/Library_List